# Stripe Connect - can sellers create there own products using custom products creator rather than use stripes dashboard

Tags: stripe-payments

Can you create a custom products creator with your website instead of using stripes dashboard and also create a custom shopping cart?

I need sellers to create there own products on the website instead of stripes dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's API allows you to create [products](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create) and [prices](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object). I would suggest reading through Stripe's [other docs](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/overview) on products and prices so you can understand what info you need to ask your sellers for and what info you need to provide to the Stripe API.

Stripe doesn't really have a concept of a "cart". [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) can display a list of items on a payment page for you, but it is up to your code to track what  each of your end customers want to buy and what Stripe Prices and Products each of those items relates to.